# Formatting Json

Tags: jquery, json, formatting

Iam using Newtonsoft.Json

For this I have following code,

```
    [WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
    string msg = string.Empty;
    string json;

    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=working_sample;uid=root;pwd=Tetra@123;pooling=false;"))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from json_example_table where subject='Swe'", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]); 
            // Using this I am getting single letter as output 
             // IN ASPX Code is as below.....
             success: function (data) {
                var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                var obj = data.d;
                 $('#txtname').val(obj[0]); // This is giving "[" as output


     //var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
     //string jsonn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.None, settings);
        con.Close();
        }
    }

    return json;
}
```

What do i do now to get correct output...
I have tried with Formatting but its giving error as

**ERROR**

```
  ambiguous ref btwn System.Xml.Formatting and System.Json.Formatting
```

Any help Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `Newtonsoft.Json` please use correct the namespace. `Formatting` belongs to Newtonsoft.Json namespace, refer <kbd>[Documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm)</kbd>

Try with specifying namespace like `Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting`

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;

 .....
 .....
 .....
 var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
                  { Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented };
```

Comment: But namesapce name Json doesnot exist in System.., This is the error

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.JsonSerializerSettings does not contaion Formatting defination

Comment: @Pink, `JsonSerializerSettings` belongs to `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace and not `Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting`. Please read my answer clearly

Comment: Still the same error.. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings does not contaion Formatting defination  I am using same as you have given

Comment: Should do, is in documentation: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Formatting.htm - you may want to check that you are using a recent version of Newtonsoft.JSON.

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan.., Giving in these way is also working fine  json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0], Formatting.Indented); But My mistake was I have using both Newtonsoft.Json; and System.Xml., so ambiguity problem has occurred

Comment: @Pink, That is what i said, please use the correct namespace to avoid conflict :) Good that you identified

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan But As I am using this My output is same but when checked tru Debugger its Formatted In aspx I am using as  var objdata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                    var obj = data.d;          
                        $('#txtname').val(obj[0]);
Is this correct or any corrections in This also

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan can you Please Input this Info in Your ans so that i can accept as It helped me a lot...

Comment: @Pink, you need not to use `$.parseJSON`, if you set content type `application/json` in your server. Check out the response content type set, if it is `text/html or text/plain` you need to convert the string to JSON format using `$.parseJSON`. But in modern browser like firefox, chrome, IE8+ you can use `JSON.parse` to do the same :)

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan Yes I am getting Data But its like a single letter.., Like 1st Text box is getting "["., 2nd Textbox "'" and 3rd textbox "d" as output.., instead of Words in each textboxes I am getting letters in each Text box....